# How to put And and OR filter type when RetrieveMultiple query is Fetch Expression

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, powerapps-modeldriven

Please advice how to filter CRM/Model Driven App Unified Client Interface View using below same query expression in RetrieveMultiple plugin when input parameter query is of type Fetch Expression:

```
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);

string[] sourceChannel = new string[] { "Central Bank", "AECB" };

FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("sourcechannelidname", ConditionOperator.NotIn, sourceChannel));
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

FilterExpression filter2 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("sourcechannelidname", ConditionOperator.In, sourceChannel));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("valid", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

FilterExpression filter3 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("sourcechannelidname", ConditionOperator.In, sourceChannel));
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("valid", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("reopeningcount", ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, 0));
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

FilterExpression filter4 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("sourcechannelidname", ConditionOperator.In, sourceChannel));
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("valid", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 0));
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

filter.AddFilter(filter1);
filter.AddFilter(filter2);
filter.AddFilter(filter3);
filter.AddFilter(filter4);

qe.Criteria.AddFilter(filter);
```

I tried below by taking help from Microsoft documentation as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/org-service/samples/modify-query-preoperation-stage

But I don't have any idea how to put And and OR filter type in below XML Document.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated a lot.

```
entityElement.Add(
  new XElement("filter",
    new XElement("condition",
      new XAttribute("attribute", "sourcechannelidname"),
      new XAttribute("operator", "not-in"), //not equal
      new XElement("value", new XText("Central Bank")),
      new XElement("value", new XText("AECB"))
    ),
    new XElement("condition",
      new XAttribute("attribute", "casetypecode"),
      new XAttribute("operator", "eq"), //equal
      new XAttribute("value", "1"), //Complaints
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: generate the xml using Advanced Find or FetchXML Builder (inside XrmToolBox), it's easier that way

Comment: There is difference between fetchXML and XML doc like I have mentioned above in last code. How can we apply And and OR operator with filter type?

Comment: I know there is a difference between writing a simple xml and inserting placeholders to change the values and building the same xml using XElement and XAttribute, if you want to complicate your life be my guest

Comment: Can you please show me how can we achieve it for fetch expression using Fetch XML with an example?

Comment: int countLimit = 2;
string fetch = $"<fetch mapping='logical' count='{countLimit}'><entity name='account'><attribute name='accountid'/><attribute name='name'/></entity></fetch>";
EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

Comment: My friend, I am trying to modifying the existing view query in retrieve multiple plugin  Prevalidation stage and what you are telling doesn't help. CRM Online now uses modern UI and for view the query is of type fetch expression which is edited in XML Doc format as I mentioned above. I'm wandering if there is any linq to XML way for doing it in which I can easily apply And OR filter condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FetchXml the expression you're trying to write is (see the `type='and'`):

```xml
<filter type='and' >
  <condition attribute='sourcechannelidname' operator='not-in' >
    <value>Central Bank</value>
    <value>AECB</value>
  </condition>
  <condition attribute='casetypecode' operator='eq' value='1' >
</filter>
```

So I think you just need to specify an `XAttribute` on the "filter" `XElement`

```cs
entityElement.Add(
  new XElement("filter",
    new XAttribute("type", "and"),
    new XElement("condition",
      new XAttribute("attribute", "sourcechannelidname"),
      new XAttribute("operator", "not-in"), //not equal
      new XElement("value", new XText("Central Bank")),
      new XElement("value", new XText("AECB"))
    ),
    new XElement("condition",
      new XAttribute("attribute", "casetypecode"),
      new XAttribute("operator", "eq"), //equal
      new XAttribute("value", "1"), //Complaints
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

XrmToolbox can now parse C# into a fetch expression. Just use the "View" menu and choose "QueryExpression" to get it to pull open the window, then type (or paste) your valid code into it and click "Parse" and it will turn it into FetchXml for you.
You didn't include the full fetchXml query, and I didn't recognize the field names, but I copied it to the OOTB incident query (since I knew it had a casetypecode field) and replaced the field names with the same type. I made them parameters so you can easily replace them with your own params. Here is the code I used:

```
// Instantiate QueryExpression query
var query = new QueryExpression("incident");
query.TopCount = 50;

// Add all columns to query.ColumnSet
query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;

FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);

string[] sourceChannel = new string[] { "Central Bank", "AECB" };
var stringColName = "ticketnumber";
var intColName = "timezoneruleversionnumber";
var pickColName = "servicestage";

FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(stringColName, ConditionOperator.NotIn, sourceChannel));
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

FilterExpression filter2 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(stringColName, ConditionOperator.In, sourceChannel));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(pickColName , ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

FilterExpression filter3 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(stringColName, ConditionOperator.In, sourceChannel));
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(pickColName , ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(intColName, ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, 0));
filter3.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

FilterExpression filter4 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(stringColName, ConditionOperator.In, sourceChannel));
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(pickColName , ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 0));
filter4.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("casetypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));

filter.AddFilter(filter1);
filter.AddFilter(filter2);
filter.AddFilter(filter3);
filter.AddFilter(filter4);

query.Criteria.AddFilter(filter);
```

and this is the filter it created:

```
<filter type="and" >
  <filter type="or" >
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="ticketnumber" operator="not-in" >
        <value>Central Bank</value>
        <value>AECB</value>
      </condition>
      <condition attribute="casetypecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="ticketnumber" operator="in" >
        <value>Central Bank</value>
        <value>AECB</value>
      </condition>
      <condition attribute="servicestage" operator="eq" value="1" />
      <condition attribute="casetypecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="ticketnumber" operator="in" >
        <value>Central Bank</value>
        <value>AECB</value>
      </condition>
      <condition attribute="servicestage" operator="eq" value="2" />
      <condition attribute="timezoneruleversionnumber" operator="gt" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="casetypecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="ticketnumber" operator="in" >
        <value>Central Bank</value>
        <value>AECB</value>
      </condition>
      <condition attribute="servicestage" operator="eq" value="2" />
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="ne" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="casetypecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
  </filter>
</filter>
```